# getZoom and getVisibleBounds methods never resolve in @mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl Android

Tags: android, react-native, mapbox-gl

**Problem**

Issue while getting mapbox bounds coordinates using this.map refereance `@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl` npm module. I used `getVisibleBounds()` method but it will not resolve promise any how.

```js
try {
      let bounds = await this.map.getVisibleBounds();

      console.log("Bounds : ", bounds);
    } catch (err) {
       console.log("Error : ", err);
     }
```

I used below dependecy for React-Native App with Android.

```
"@mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl": "6.1.2-beta2"

"react": "16.3.1"

"react-native": "0.55.4"
```

It will neither print Bounds nor Error

Any please help me solve out this problem

There is issue raise on gitgub mapbox repo as well but they also didn't reply on this issue. You can check on below link for more details.

[Reported same issue on Github too](https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/1353)

Comment: Have you checked the phone error log when you fire the method? `adb logcat`

Comment: Thanks for comment, But I am using Android Studio emulator. So currently i am in debugging mode. as i said i didn't get any error for this but not getting result as well.

Comment: I'll quickly give it a go.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may not be the issue, but, are you getting this in your logcat console in your Android Studio?

```
09-19 11:15:01.070 5390-5390/com.endurance W/unknown:ReactNative: Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed: RCTEventEmitter.receiveEvent([913,"rct.mapbox.map.androidcallback",{"payload":{"visibleBounds":[[-121.96388609239466,37.47651057926733],[-122.2038196399402,37.36744637395246]]},"type":"1537352098529"}])
Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed: RCTEventEmitter.receiveEvent([913,"rct.mapbox.map.change",{"payload":{},"type":"didfinishrenderingmapfully"}])
Calling JS function after bridge has been destroyed: RCTEventEmitter.receiveEvent([913,"rct.mapbox.map.change",{"payload":{},"type":"didfinishloadingmap"}])
```

It seems that event is emitted after the bridge has been destroyed. If you are debugging, try to close your debugger console (React Native Debugger), disable Live Reload/Hot Reload > Rebuild.

It seems that some events are killed in debug process, see mapbox issue here:

https://github.com/mapbox/react-native-mapbox-gl/issues/1189

Comment: Yes, you are right for this. but with `abd logcat` i unable to see console.log statemement for printing Bounds. as other console.log() is printed in logcat. but i didn't get console as i print in my code. is there any solution for that?

Comment: I want to add more information about this. If we create android apk and install that apk in mobile then its work. instead of console.log() i put alert and install apk in my mobile and that's working as expected. but my problem is i need to do lot of code with this. So i am confuse that how to implement futher task for application. 

Thanks @JRK

Comment: @JaydipshihVaghela could you also upvote the answer if it helped you? :) - I'll see if there's any other way we could work around this, I had the same issue with onPress.

Comment: if you found this question is useful and clear then please upvote for the same

Comment: @JaydipshihVaghela Try to down grade mapbox to  `6.1.2`

Comment: I have downgrade the version to `6.1.2` by yesterday but didn't work. is it working with your code?